# Need a VBA code. rename sheets from list

Tags: vba, table-rename

Need a VBA code. rename sheets from list

I have a list of names in sheet 2 cell w3 thru w22. I need to name sheets/tabs 3 thur 22 from the the list of names.   The names change. 
and if no name in w3 thru w22. I want the tabs to be numbered 1 thru 20 
Any Ideas?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a community-run website where programmers answer questions about **specific coding issues**. Unfortunately, questions asking the community to provide code given a set of specifications are outside the scope of this site. Please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the [help/on-topic] for all the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range, Dim i As Integer 

    Set MyRange = Sheets("Summary").Range("w3") 
    Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown)) 

    For Each MyCell In MyRange 
    If MyCell.Value IS NULL
    Sheets(Sheets.Count + 3).Name = i
    Sheets(Sheets.Count + 3).Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet 
    Next MyCell
```

Or something like this maybe, I didn't test it since you didn't give us anything to go off of or make any effort to solve it yourself.
    http://en.kioskea.net/faq/27361-excel-a-macro-to-create-and-name-worksheets-based-on-a-list Kudos to this website for giving me a basis to go off of.

Comment: Yes I might be a little lame.    Just can't seem to figure it out.   Thank you for your answer.

Comment: It's ok, just read the link Mat's Mug sent you and it'll help you learn how to ask much better questions. Everyone has to learn and practice :)